# Всплывающее окошко

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Вчера начал изучать JavaScript, и сразу возникло желание написать всплывающее окошко. Возможно ли это реаливать на JS. Если можно, то покажите пару  пару легких примеров,пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: на хешкоде были вопросы по устройству модальных окон.

Answer (score 1):

хм..JQuery UI - там и всплывающие окошки, и кнопочки, и календарики и куча разного тому подобного. Заодно, если хватит терпения, можете изучить исходный код самой библиотеки JQuery - это хороший шанс посмотреть, как пишут на JavaScript большие умные дяди, благодаря чему сможете неплохо вырасти над собой.
И еще. Открою вам страшный секрет, но JavaScript - это далеко не только всплывающие окошки и прочая ерунда. Учите лучше сам язык.

Comment: Та я знаю)) Просто хотел попробовать)

Answer (score 1):

```
http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/pravilnye-modalnye-okna
```

здесь автор описывает как создать модальные окна.

P.S. А если серьезно - то лучше `http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/`. Там есть все.